# get selected value between li asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="tree3">
@foreach (var item1 in Model.Departments.Where(s => s.Id == 3)) //Teknik Destek
{ 
<ul>
<li data="isFolder: true, icon: 'folder_docs.gif'">@Ajax.ActionLink(item1.DepartmentName, "Index", new { item1.Id }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Get" });
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.Users.Where(s => s.DepartmentId == 3))
{
<li>
@Ajax.ActionLink(item.UserName, "Index", new { item.Id }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Get" });
</li>
}
</ul>
</ul>
}
</div>
```

How can i get selected value between li Please help me i am trying for 3 days i can not take selected value inside li

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink("EditUser", "Index", "Index", new { RID = item.Id }, null, new AjaxOptions
               {
                   HttpMethod = "Get",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                   UpdateTargetId = "dialog-add-user",


               })
```

or try like this

```
 @Html.ActionLink("EditUser", "Index", new { Id =  item.Id })
```